# Close DB connection in Remix

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector

I am building my first remix app and wonder how to close a database connection? I use a pool connection (mysql2) so that the connections are reused if possible.

I need the database connection in each route, so I don't know in advance when I can close the connection.

If the user leaves the app, then the connections stays open.

Is there a possibility (e.g. exit hook) to close the connection in remix?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, the remix tag you selected relates to ethereum development, nothing to do with javascript web development framework you refer to.